# Jquery Appending Multiple Images

Tags: jquery, image, append

I'm trying to make a background theme using a picture. Right now, I'm just trying to get a row, but I plan on making a whole landscape of these (and other) tiles. What I'm trying to do is append new s into the HTML but with `style="left:$tleft; etc`;"

This is under the Jquery :

```
var $tleft = 0;
var $newTerrain = $('<img id=$tleft, style="height:100px; width:100px; left:$tleft; top:0; display:inline-block; position:relative;", src="http://i.imgur.com/bb3aCjO.png">');
var $etc
```

and inside the document.ready I have:

```
while($tleft<=600) {
    $newTerrain.appendTo('#Terrain'); 
    $tleft+=100;

    console.log("Terrain placed? "+$tleft);
}
```

I was hoping that it would place 6 newTerrain images with each one being 100px further from the left because of the `"left:$tleft"` in the newTerrain var, but this apparently isn't the case. Please help!

Comment: Please write your own answer and accept it to indicate that the problem is solved. See also: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, jQuery doesn't have any sort of templating engine, so the attempted variable interpolation (`<img id=$tleft'`) won't work. You'll need to set the left value within the loop. See this bin: http://jsbin.com/cujiyaro/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

you need to clone the object you are appending. also you need to update the position either using the offset or css jquery methods.

[Take a look at this jsfiddle to see what i mean](http://jsfiddle.net/camos052585/vW7DF/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var tile = $('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/bb3aCjO.png">');
var root = $('#Terrain');

for (var y = 0; y < 100; y += 20) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 100; x += 20) {
        var p={top: y,left: x};
        var stamp = tile.clone();            
        root.append(stamp);
        stamp.offset(p);
    }
}
});
```